# Magento email sent to spam

Tags: php, magento, email, vps

I'm runnning an online store using Magento on a VPS I own with a dedicated IP address.
The problem I'm facing is that all emails are sent to SPAM.

I've read that shared servers / IPs can have problems and be flagged as SPAM but I believe my case is different.

When the email is sent, in the email header, I get something like: "Sent from example@mydomain.com *through* strange.server.name.com" like what happens for codewars.com emails (Codewars info@codewars.com *through* mail130.wdc02.mcdlv.net). Gmail sends the emails from my domain to SPAM but for codewars, to the inbox, so there is no problem in this.

What do I need to configure (in Magento and/or server) to solve this? I don't use any tool like cpanel...

Comment: I'm sure there's a canonical dupe around here somewhere, but just go read this for now: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html

Answer (score 2):

We worked around this issue by first by configuring `postfix` correctly (take a look at your `/etc/postfix` files). The problem areas you should look for is the `myhostname`, `myorigin` and other local delivery maps if there are any.

Doing this, did work for us for a little bit (like a few weeks). However what gave us a more permanent solution was to move our outgoing mail (SMTP) via services like [mailgun](http://www.mailgun.com). There are tons of options including Google Apps for Business.